# Show each div total amount in one div with every new action in jquery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

Javascript Code:

```
$(document).on('click', '#google_analytics', function() {
    if ($("#google_analytics").prop('checked') == true) {
        var google_analytics_cost = $('#google_analytics_cost').val();
        $('.total-amount12').text(google_analytics_cost);
    } else {
        $('.total-amount12').text('0');
    }
});

$(document).on('click', '#mailing_list', function() {
    if ($("#mailing_list").prop('checked') == true) {
        var mailing_cost = $('#mailing_list_cost').val();
        $('.total-amount13').text(mailing_cost);
    } else {
        $('.total-amount13').text('0');
    }
});
```

I just want to add both actions total in one div. Which is named **total-amt** `<div class="total-amt">0</div>` In this div, whenever i click any action the total should show **total-amt** div and then, if i click on other action then its total amount too added with the previous amount.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this, when you click on any action it will take the previous value from that div, convert it into integer (parseInt) then it will add newValue in it. Finally, It will put the new sum into that div again.

**Edit-1**

You need to remove the $ string from the div. Try this working snippet.

```js
//Action performed and Add the sum to that div
$('a').click(function(){
  //New value that is going to add into div
  var newValueToAdd = 10;
  //Replace the HTML with final summation
  $('.total-amt')
    .html("$" + 
          (parseInt($('.total-amt').html().replace('$', '')) + 
          newValueToAdd));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="total-amt">$0</div>
<a href="javascript:void(0)">Add</a>
```

Comment: Total amount div is like this <div class="total-amt">$0</div> here i want to add total amount.

Comment: @neha910: You need to remove the $ from your div string, then need to add the amount and put it again. Please check the updated answer

Comment: Yeah, somehow it's working but what is doing that is not adding integer value. it just append value further like this, if i have added 30, and then second time i added 50 then total should be 70 not like this 3070.

Comment: @neha910 : check now, I've created example for you.

Comment: Now it is working fine. Thank you so much for your help. it's really worth.

Comment: @neha910 no problem, accept my answer to make it worth :)